# ImageView set image Resource doesn't show wanted image.png

Tags: android, gridview, resources, imageview, gallery

In my gridViewAdapter I set the ImageResource to the .png object but it doesn't show in activity. Here's the adapter's function getView:

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    View row = convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder; 
    if (row == null) { 
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); 
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false); 
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.photoSubscriptTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.photoSubscriptTextView); 
        holder.photoInstanceImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.galleryMonumentPhotoImageView); 
        row.setTag(holder); 
    } else { 
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag(); 
    } 
    final Photo photo = data.get(position); 
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent intent; 
            if(photo.getPodpis().equals(getContext().getString(R.string.photo_add))){ 
                intent = new Intent(); 
                intent.setType("image/*"); 
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 100); 
            } 
            else { 
                intent = new Intent(context, PhotoGallery.class); 
                intent.putExtra("photo", photo); 
                context.startActivity(intent); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    holder.photoSubscriptTextView.setText(photo.getPodpis()); 
    if(photo.getUri() != null) 
        aQuery.id(holder.photoInstanceImageView).image(photo.getUri()); 
    else if(photo.getPodpis().equals(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.photo_add)))  { 
        holder.photoInstanceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_add); 
    } 
    return row;
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:padding="5dp" 
          android:clickable="true" 
          android:focusable="true"> 
<!--android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"--> 
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/galleryMonumentPhotoImageView" 
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/image_add"> 
</ImageView> 
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/photoSubscriptTextView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:textSize="12sp" > 
</TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

The main layout contains only the Relative Layout and GridView.
Can anybody tell me why image from resources that I set in adapter doesn't show in activity?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you put the onClick() method inside of getView() does not mean it has access to temporary variables created within getView().  The item clicked will likely be a different one than the getView() method last processed.  So, there is no connection between them.

You should instead put a onItemClick() listener on the ListView itself in your activity onCreate() or onCreateView() code.  That method has the position of the item that was clicked, and you can then get that item from your ArrayList using the position.

Like this:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long row_id) {
        final Photo photo = data.get(position); 
        // etc.
    }
}
```